# Having a signed tx object from mempool in js how can I rebuild raw tx data using ethersjs or web3js?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, raw-transaction, verify, sendrawtransaction

I have a pending signed tx object received through subscribe on pending transactions in js. I need to build raw tx data to be able to send it directly to the network, but the following code does not seem to work (knowing that txFields.from is the signer):

```
const sig = ethers.utils.splitSignature(sigFields);
const rawTx = ethers.utils.serializeTransaction(txFields, sig);
assertEq(await ethers.utils.verifyMessage(rawTx, sig), txFields.from, 'Invalid signer');
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the content of `txFields` and `sigFields`. I succeeded to solve it as follows:

```
const txFields = {
    chainId: parseInt(tx.chainId, 16),
    gasPrice: Number(tx.gasPrice),
    nonce: tx.nonce,
    to: tx.to,
    type: tx.type,
    value: tx.value
} as any;
if (tx.accessList) {
    txFields.accessList = tx.accessList;
}
if (tx.gas) {
    txFields.gasLimit = tx.gas;
}
if (tx.maxFeePerGas) {
    txFields.maxFeePerGas = tx.maxFeePerGas;
}
if (tx.maxPriorityFeePerGas) {
    txFields.maxPriorityFeePerGas = tx.maxPriorityFeePerGas;
}
if (tx.data || tx.input) {
    txFields.data = tx.data || tx.input;
}
if (!tx.type) {
    txFields.value = ethers.BigNumber.from(tx.value);
}
const sigFields = {
    r: tx.r,
    s: tx.s,
    v: parseInt(tx.v, 16)
} as any;

const sig = ethers.utils.splitSignature(sigFields);
const rawSignedTx = ethers.utils.serializeTransaction(txFields, sig);
```